# Omitting columns of parent-table when creating Foreign Key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

To create a Foreign Key in Oracle, some times I see

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Supplier
  FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_id)
  REFERENCES Supplier(Supplier_id)
```

But, some other times, I see this

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Supplier
  FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_id)
  REFERENCES Supplier
```

The difference is that the column `Supplier_id` comes after the table `Supplier` in the first statement but it is omitted in the second statement.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the [documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm)

> If you identify only the parent table or view and omit the column
>   name, then the foreign key **automatically references the primary key** of
>   the parent table or view. The corresponding column or columns of the
>   foreign key and the referenced key must match in order and datatype.

Comment: Thank you for both the answer and the link.

Answer (score 1):

One of the major criticisms of SQL as regards not being faithful to the relational model is reliance on column ordering. However, just because SQL includes non-relational feature it does not mean that one should use them; in fact, I feel strongly that such features should be avoided or, when avoidance is impossible,  mitigated against.

Standard SQL provides some syntax to avoid column ordering reliance (`NATURAL JOIN`, `UNION CORRESPONDING`, etc). Other syntax helps mitigate against such reliance (e.g. `INSERT INTO (<comma list of columns>) VALUES (<comma list of fields in same order>)`). `FOREIGN KEY` syntax falls into this second category.

Conclusion: always use the syntax in your first example and avoid the second.